# Analytics for a CRM to view more customer information

Tags: user-feedback, analytics

I'm integrating my inbound marketing CRM to another web application so that I can get more information from my users. Specifically, this web application allows me to create feedback forms so that I can get product inquiries, sales feedback, etc.
It helps my customers by not having them switch between two website to view information?

We're currently in the alpha phase and will be testing it with a few customers of my CRM. What should my success metrics be to decide to move forward to commercialize this integration?

Comment: Planning your metrics in advance—that's excellent!

Answer (score 1):

You can analyze a future result either on Data or on hypothesis. If you have neither of these to research for, it is difficult to look forward to the success metrics. You can look for such similar CRMs that are established and understand their quaterly reports regarding their success rate. Also those who couldn't make it and 'why' they could not.

'Data' helps more than anything else!

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at engagement rate - how successful is the feedback form; any drop off for example. You could also later dive deeper into the successful sales conversions.